# When i try to add a JSON Array, it removes the previous array. (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json

**EDIT:**
I am trying to merge 2 arrays together, saying that i want to add a new array to the json data without removing the json data that is already in the value.

EXAMPLE:
$chatjson = [] has some json data in it which will look like this:

```
$chatjson = [{"sender":"Testing","message":"Hi"}]
```

and i want to keep that data when it adds another array so it will look like this

```
$chatjson = [{"sender":"Testing","message":"Hi"},{"sender":"Testing","message":"Message 2!"}]
```

Should support my question.

```
<?php 
  include '../filter.php';
  $chatjson = [];
  $sender = SecurePost($_POST["sender"]);
  $message = SecurePost($_POST["message"]);

  if ($sender || $message) {
      $chatarray = array('sender' => $sender, 'message' => $message);
      $decodejson = json_decode($chatjson, true);

      $merge = array_merge((array)$chatarray, (array)$decodejson);
      $chatjson = json_encode($merge);
      echo $chatjson;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have set it to empty: `$chatjson = [];`

Comment: I did at the top $chatjson = [];

Comment: Yes, then you do `$decodejson = json_decode($chatjson, true);` => `$decodejson` gets empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code little bit:-

```
<?php 
  include '../filter.php';
  $chatjson = Array(); // define array like this
  $sender = SecurePost($_POST["sender"]);
  $message = SecurePost($_POST["message"]);

  if ($sender || $message) {
      $chatarray[] = array('sender' => $sender, 'message' => $message); // assign values every time to a new index.
      $decodejson = json_decode($chatjson, true);

      $merge = array_merge((array)$chatarray, (array)$decodejson); // push the new data
      $chatjson = json_encode($merge);
      echo $chatjson;
  }
?>
```